# NestJs CQRS Event Handler logic

Tags: event-handling, nestjs, domain-driven-design, cqrs

When using NestJS and their `EventHandlers` - is the idea that the logic to call the other services lives within the module that's emitting events handler? I would have thought there would have been an 'event subscriber' from within another module that would receive notification of that event, and act within its own module.

For Example, this is my `ChampionAssignedHandler` which gets hit when I commit an event from within the Champion modules command handler. Does this handle method then inject the other module/services logic within here? Doesn't quite seem right (not very DDD).

```
import { EventsHandler, IEventHandler } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { ChampionAssignedPlayerEvent } from './champion-assigned.event';

@EventsHandler(ChampionAssignedPlayerEvent)
export class ChampionAssignedHandler
  implements IEventHandler<ChampionAssignedPlayerEvent>
{
  async handle({ championId, playerId }: ChampionAssignedPlayerEvent) {
    Logger.log('CHAMPION ASSIGNED PLAYER EVENT: ' + championId, playerId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An event can have multiple handlers and each module can optionally implement one or multiple of these handlers.

For example, your `Notifier` module may have something like `NotifyPlayersWhenChampionAssigned` that will send an email to all other participants whenever a champion is assigned.

You may also have a `HallOfFame` module that might also have a handler for this event such as `RegisterWinWhenChampionAssinged` which will require services from `HallOfFame` to execute it's own logic.